# Change navigation bar button text color

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating a custom view to generate navigation bar items.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,35)];
        UIButton *myBackButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
        [myBackButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,35)];
        myBackButton.titleLabel.text = @"Back";
        myBackButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        myBackButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        myBackButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [myBackButton setEnabled:YES];
        [myBackButton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(moveBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [backButtonView addSubview:myBackButton];
        [myBackButton release];
        UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
        [backButtonView release];
        [backButton release];


        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(300, 0, 400, 35);
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.text = @"Order booking";
        self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    }
    return self;
}
```

With this I am having the following output :

[image]

I want the bar button to have same background color as navigation bar and its text in black color. I have tried doing it the either way by using **UINavigationController** delegate, but didn't get success. 
What changes do I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the 5.0 documentation. There was a WWDC '11 session on this very thing about a new, and much easier way, to do this. (Session 114 - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls).

Comment: where can i download or see 5.0 documention.may i install this in xcode 3.please help me.where can i download all new sample code of WWDC.thanku .i awaiting for ur early reply

Comment: You can find all the sessions [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).  Session 114 is called "Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls". You need to be logged in with your Apple ID to see it.

Comment: To code for the iOS 5 SDK, you need Xcode 4.2. Currently, there is some sample code from the sessions but they are only available, thus far, to WWDC attendees. I'm guessing the documentation for new iOS 5 APIs hasn't been finished yet and hasn't been posted. The sessions do walk you through a fair amount of code though.

Answer (score 4):

Here how to change the text label color (e.g. to black) of a UIBarButtonItem (the text label is white colored by default):

```
[self.myBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Especially when you choose a light colored tint (background color) of the button:

```
self.myBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

And not to forget, you may also want to change the text label shadow color:
(the code should be placed before changing the text label color itself, in order not to have the shadow redrawn on top of the text label color!)

```
[self.fullVersionViewButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor grayColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: `UITextAttributeTextColor`  changed to `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` in swift4.0 it would be `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor`